# How to get DateTimeZone Name from a dateTimeZone offset value

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to create a (joda) DateTimeZone object from a time zone string representation, like , or "GMT -05:30"?

OR

There is any alternate way to get 'IST' from "GMT -05:30" or from gmtoffsetValue.

Comment: A Zone name represents a political entity (a government that makes decisions about zoning inside it, daylight savings etc). The offset doesn't tell you which of all the political entities along that time offset is responsible for this particular instant.

Comment: If you know you have a fixed offset, then see Robin's answer below.  But in general - many time zones do *not* have fixed offsets, and thus the operation you requested is not possible.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 1):

If the input string has a fixed format, you can parse the offset using a regular expression and then get the corresponding `DateTimeZone` object by the [`DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMillis(int, int)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forOffsetHoursMinutes-int-int-) method.

Answer (score 0):

String[] timezones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(offset);

more info in:
http://www.javacoderanch.com/how-to-get-timezone-ids-by-their-milliseconds-offset.html